# Uniqueness of LU factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Can someone help me show that if a *non singular matrix* has a standard $LU$ factorisation, then it must be unique? I know how to do $LU$ factorisation but I don't think is of any use here..

Comment: You mean Theorem $9.5$ in theses [*notes*](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/wendland/teaching/mt201011/part4.pdf)?

Comment: @ Variable Yes quite. But is it given there how to price that product of two lower triangular matrices is also lower triangular?

Comment: What do you mean price?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  I meant prove..

Comment: Start with a $2x2$ lower triangular matrix, prove that as the base case and then use induction. I am not sure why you want to prove that for two lower triangular matrices, but have at it.